# What are the incentive of some std::ranges::XXX_n?

Tags: c++, c++20, stl-algorithm, std-ranges

Looking through the algorithm library, there are a few `std::ranges::XXX_n` function have basically the same definition as their `std::XXX_n` counterparts, namely `copy_n`, `fill_n`, and `generate_n`.

The only difference between them are the ranges version often applied more `concept` and `requires` to the parameters, which probably should be added to the non-range version anyways(I mean it doesn't make sense to call a generator that is not `invokable`, or copy something that is not `copyable`); Plus you can't apply execution policy on them because they meant to be ranges.

So my guess is just to have a unifying way of calling things, or am I totally missing something?

Comment: I presume the ranges versions are meant to be used in the ranges idiomatic fashion.  Other than that, they're probably more-or-less thunks to the algorithm counterparts.

Comment: @Eljay I thought so, but `ranges::XXX_n`s requires a starting iterator, so neither `R | XXX_n(...)` nor `XXX_n(R, ...)`would work.

Comment: I think the idea for a lot of the constrained algorithms is that while most of the concepts and requirements used just reflect prerequisites the C++17 and earlier versions were already expecting, they're not _exactly_ the same and some existing code would be invalidated if `std::copy_n` got updated instead of superseded by `std::ranges::copy_n`.